# Docker Swarm agent - invalid mount config for type

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, ubuntu-20.04, docker-swarm-mode

On one of our `docker swarm agent` server `docker ps -a` doesn't show any list of running containers. From `docker service status` seeing below messages.

```
$ sudo systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-11-13 17:04:36 IST; 15h ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 4834 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 74
     Memory: 119.0M
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             └─4834 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

Nov 14 08:27:06 svr-3 dockerd[4834]: time="2021-11-14T08:27:06.848315565+05:30" level=error msg="fatal task error" error="invalid mount config for type \"b>
Nov 14 08:27:07 svr-3 dockerd[4834]: time="2021-11-14T08:27:07.253824118+05:30" level=error msg="fatal task error" error="invalid mount config for type \"b>
Nov 14 08:27:11 svr-3 dockerd[4834]: time="2021-11-14T08:27:11.841725172+05:30" level=error msg="fatal task error" error="invalid mount config for type \"b>
Nov 14 08:27:12 svr-3 dockerd[4834]: time="2021-11-14T08:27:12.261848748+05:30" level=error msg="fatal task error" error="invalid mount config for type \"b>
Nov 14 08:27:16 svr-3 dockerd[4834]: time="2021-11-14T08:27:16.842731139+05:30" level=error msg="fatal task error" error="invalid mount config for type \"b>
Nov 14 08:27:17 svr-3 dockerd[4834]: time="2021-11-14T08:27:17.256307583+05:30" level=error msg="fatal task error" error="invalid mount config for type \"b>
Nov 14 08:27:21 svr-3 dockerd[4834]: time="2021-11-14T08:27:21.855252126+05:30" level=error msg="fatal task error" error="invalid mount config for type \"b>
Nov 14 08:27:22 svr-3 dockerd[4834]: time="2021-11-14T08:27:22.256813458+05:30" level=error msg="fatal task error" error="invalid mount config for type \"b>
Nov 14 08:27:26 svr-3 dockerd[4834]: time="2021-11-14T08:27:26.844842718+05:30" level=error msg="fatal task error" error="invalid mount config for type \"b>
Nov 14 08:27:27 svr-3 dockerd[4834]: time="2021-11-14T08:27:27.265032144+05:30" level=error msg="fatal task error" error="invalid mount config for type \"b>
```

On Docker Swarm Manager host nodes status shown as `ready` and `active`

```
$ docker node ls
ID                            HOSTNAME   STATUS    AVAILABILITY   MANAGER STATUS   ENGINE VERSION
mmbxdeerfwperedsbj6l8zr71f *   svr-1     Ready     Active         Leader           20.10.7
kzc7jf7irsereed3kurcwqjb2j     svr-2     Ready     Active                          20.10.7
ew0edluvz39aregd87ld0wnv2e     svr-3     Ready     Active                          18.06.1-ce
```

On `svr-3` host everything working fine. I have tried below services to solve on `svr-2`, Unfortunately couldn't help me.

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload 
sudo systemctl enable docker 
sudo systemctl start docker
```

On Leader host mount part as follows.

```
docker inspect m64

"Mounts": [
                        {
                            "Type": "bind",
                            "Source": "/data/m64/",
                            "Target": "/root/.m64/"
                        },
```

I'm new to docker swarm i really appreciate if someone help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with `svr-3` server volume `/data/m64/`, sym link was missing. have created symbolic link and problem solved.